# Installing 32-bit libraries to run Second_Life_3_8_2_303583_i686

Tags: software-recommendation, 64-bit, 32-bit

How to install 32-bit libraries to run Second_Life_3_8_2_303583_i686 on a 64-bit 16.04?

```
gaius@gaius-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
lib32ncurses5 is already the newest version (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1).
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
gaius@gaius-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ 

gaius@gaius-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
lib32z1 is already the newest version (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4).
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
```

Comment: Install both the packages using `sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5:i386 lib32z1:i386`

Comment: yes, my question is:  how to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?

Comment: gaius@gaius-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5:i386 lib32z1:i386 
[sudo] password di gaius: 
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto lib32ncurses5:i386
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto lib32z1:i386
gaius@gaius-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: into my pc run UBUNTO 16.04 LTS - 64bit

Answer (score 0):

That's an old version, better to try a newer one like 4.0.5.  But Linden Labs never got the voice fix applied, so you would still need to track down some old libraries yourself.  A better solution is to use the 64 bit Kokua viewer, which got the voice fix working, and no 32 bit libraries needed at all.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice; inworld i need use a good viewer for listening the objects on marketplace of SL